# How can I save best guess (higher/lower)

Tags: javascript, numbers

for example my toGuess number is 50 and my best lower guess is 48 but I guess 47 and it changes my best lower guess to that 47.

What I mean by this is that I want it not go lower anymore

Same thing with the higher guess

I want it to save/lock my best guess to the closest

```
'use strict'
var toGuess = Math.floor(Math.random() * (100 + 1));
console.log("To Guess: " + toGuess);
var guess = undefined;
var amount = 0;
var bestHigher = 100;
var bestLower = 0;
var hint = document.getElementById('hint');
var numbers = document.getElementById('numbers');
var lower = document.getElementById('lower');
var higher = document.getElementById('higher');

function GuessDone() {
var put = document.getElementById('number').value;
guess = Number(put);
console.log("Guess: " + guess);
document.getElementById('form').reset();


amount = amount + 1;
console.log("Guesses " + amount);

var numberDif = Number(toGuess) - Number(put);
var bestLower = Number(put) > toGuess;
var bestHigher = Number(put) < toGuess;

if (numberDif > bestLower) {
    bestLower = Number(put);
    console.log("Lower " + bestLower); 
}

if (numberDif < bestHigher) {
    bestHigher = Number(put);
    console.log("Higher " + bestHigher);
}

if (guess > toGuess) {
    hint.innerHTML = "You need to guess lower";
    higher.innerHTML = "Best guess above " + bestHigher;
} else if (guess < toGuess) {
    hint.innerHTML = "You need to guess higher";
    lower.innerHTML = "Best guess below " + bestLower;
} else {
    hint.innerHTML = "Congratz, " + toGuess + " was right! Guesses " + amount;
    var print = "";
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i <= toGuess; i++) {
        print += i + "<br>";
    }
    numbers.innerHTML = print;
}

return false;
```

## EDIT

This is my html

```
    <form id="form">
    <label for="number">Guess number between 0-100: </label>
    <input id="number" type="text" name="number">
    <button type="submit">Guess</button>
    </form>
    <p id="lower"></p>
    <p id="higher"></p>
    <p id="hint"></p>
    <p id="numbers"></p>

    <script src="numbergame.js"></script>
```

## FIDDLE

https://jsfiddle.net/d3761nbj/2/

Comment: Can you post a workin code snippet demonstrating your problem?

Comment: Also add your HTML in this./

Comment: You have `var bestLower = Number(put) > toGuess;` and then you have `numberDif > bestLower`, you're comparing a `boolean` (`bestLower`) with a `Number` (`numberDif`), that is probably not what you're looking for.